# Windows Vista looks like XP post update

Tags: windows-vista, windows-update, appearance, feature-regression

The other day the 'Windows Update' service prompted me for several important updates that were available. I sieved the ones that read 'Update for Microsoft Windows' and installed them. Here's a pic of these installed updates:

[image]

When I flipped my laptop on post these updates today, I was repulsed to find my Vista having regressed to an XP look. This is what an eyesore it has become now:

[image]

I scoured around my 'Application Settings' and the Web hoping to find a solution, however to no avail so far.

I'd be ecstatic if someone were to aid me out of this predicament!

Comment: Looks like Aero is disabled.  Verify your display drivers are installed.  Of course you clearly have selected a different color scheme.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - I will let him self-answer his question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from *Ramhound*:

> Looks like Aero is disabled. Verify your display drivers are
>   installed. Try to reinstall the graphic driver.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've disabled restore points, Windows Update creates a restore point prior to installing a batch of updates.

Do a system restore to that restore point to remove this batch of updates. If you're right that the change was caused by the updates, this should return your normal appearance.

Then you can selectively apply updates till you find the offending one, which you can exclude using the same process if you choose to do so.

Comment: Thanks, but I resorted to re-installing the Display Driver as @ramhound  suggested, and after a restart, my system's pleasing appearance is back!